# Converting AAC to MP3

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert AAC to MP3 on a Pi using `ffmpeg`. This is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.aac -acodec mp3 -ac 2 -ab 160 audio.mp3
```

It works fine on my Ubuntu machine. But on my Pi it states this:

> Unknown encoder 'mp3'

I've made sure that `liblame` and `lame` are both installed. So that's there. I also have `libavcodec53` installed. But still no go.

**EDIT:**

I have run:

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep mp3
```

This is what I get:

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1+rpi1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 31 2013 13:58:10 with gcc 4.6.3
  EA    libmp3lame      libmp3lame MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A D  mp3             MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A D  mp3adu          ADU (Application Data Unit) MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A D  mp3adufloat     ADU (Application Data Unit) MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A D  mp3float        MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A D  mp3on4          MP3onMP4
 D A D  mp3on4float     MP3onMP4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting codec list of currently installed encoders:

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep mp3
```

This outputs the list of available codecs:

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1+rpi1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 31 2013 13:58:10 with gcc 4.6.3
  EA    libmp3lame      libmp3lame MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A D  mp3             MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A D  mp3adu          ADU (Application Data Unit) MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A D  mp3adufloat     ADU (Application Data Unit) MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A D  mp3float        MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A D  mp3on4          MP3onMP4
 D A D  mp3on4float     MP3onMP4
```

Running `ffmpeg` with another codec selected from the codec list:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.aac -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160 audio.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

Check what encoders were built into your build of ffmpeg.

It's not simply a matter of having libraries installed, ffmpeg must have been built to use those libraries and associate them with a given encoder.

More than likely, your build on the Raspberry Pi was not built with an mp3 encoder but your Ubuntu build was. You can check what encoders are available using the command:

`ffmpeg -encoders`

If you don't see anything there with mp3 in the second column, then your ffmpeg wasn't built with mp3 encoder support - at least not using `-acodec mp3`.

You can try looking through all the included encoders. There may be another name associated with some MP3 encoder, but more than likely you will either need to obtain a build of ffmpeg for your pi that can use liblame or you will have to build it yourself with lame support enabled.